# How do I darken up print on individual websites?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, display

I am running Windows XP, using Mozilla Firefox as my browser. I've run across many websites where I have to squint my 72 year old eyes to read the printed matter on the page. I know Firefox has a solution for that under Options --> Content --> Colors, then uncheck the box for "allow pages to chose their own colors, instead of my selection above". That, of course, does the trick, for the moment. Then I have to go back and put a check back in the box. My question is, is there an add-on or software that will allow me to add websites to a white list that will darken the print on a particular website every time I use it?

By the way, my monitor is an Acer LCD model # AL2016W Bbd, if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [NoSquint Firefox Extension](http://urandom.ca/nosquint/) remembers font and background colours (along with zoom settings) on a site by site basis.

After installing, you can set the text colour for a site by clicking the zoom icons in the status bar

[image]

[image]

(hopefully the truncated dialog box buttons in Windows 7 will be fixed soon)

Comment: All good answers, but this one was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to all who took the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, remember making your monitor darker may be useful, or even buying some tinted glasses.

Try taking a look at [this](http://www.informationliberation.com/?id=26968) article and trying the suggestions there. Essentially, you can use themes to change how the pages look.

I hope that helps! I absolutely have the same problem sometimes.

Incase the link ever goes down, here it is:

> If you're like me you can get a bit of
>   a head ache if you're staring into a
>   white web page for too long, well
>   yesterday I did some searching and I
>   came across what I feel is a really
>   nice add-on for firefox, if you want
>   to see the end result check out this
>   picture here:
>
> It is the product of a few themes /
>   add-ons, first the darkness from the
>   page requires an add-on called
>   "Stylish" which allows you to download
>   a bunch of themes which will change
>   the colors of websites automatically.
>   Download stylish here:
>   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108
>
> Then you need to get a specific theme,
>   the one I am running is called "Carbon
>   eXtreme" which you can download here:
>   http://userstyles.org/styles/16996
>
> If you want to search for other themes
>   I suggest searching "Global Styles" as
>   those ones apply globally to all the
>   sites you visit.
>   http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/global/all/popularity/desc/1
>
> There is another nice style add-on
>   which makes the screen when you first
>   open a new page black instead of
>   white, it's called "about:blank black"
>   and you can check it out here:
>   http://userstyles.org/styles/5613
>
> Lastly, the darkened firefox is from
>   "PitchDark 3.5.0" which can be
>   downloaded here:
>   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1529
>
> So basically this is a nice way to
>   make this page darker if you don't
>   like it being too white, we plan to in
>   the future program something into the
>   page to make a similar dark theme
>   without the need for any programs like
>   this. - Chris, IL

Comment: Nice suggestion - I was about to go make a User JS for it, but looks like that article has it all!

Answer (score 1):

If you know a bit of CSS, or are willing to learn, the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) extension would allow you to customise pages to your heart's content.

Comment: It can also be useful in adblocking, with the `display:none` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, maybe [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy thing to try is bump the font size up in Firefox; maybe you won't have to work with themes or CSS. Control + increases, Control - decreases.

Answer (score 0):

Before dipping the website into developer burn some extra light onto the text of the page, dodging the graphics and other elements you don't want darkened.

There are also [user](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm) [stylesheets](http://www.squarefree.com/userstyles/user-style-sheets.html) in firefox. With some recommendations at [this site](http://www.squarefree.com/userstyles/) and [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org/).

One possible rule could be:

```
* {
  font-family: serif ! important;
  color: black ! important;
  background-color: white !important
  }
```

That said, there are plugins that manage user styles per site too.

If you need this on a rarer occasion you might like to use Firebug to edit styles live. It's a bit tricky to get used to though.

Finally there's accessibility features in [Mac OS](http://www.apple.com/accessibility/macosx/vision.html) and probably Win XP that try to up the contrast of everything.

> **Using a high contrast theme**
>   On Windows and Linux-based systems,
>   Firefox automatically detects if you
>   are using a high contrast theme and
>   displays everything in your high
>   contrast color scheme. This overrides
>   all other other browser or web page
>   settings, and it affects the Firefox
>   interface itself (all menus, windows,
>   and dialog boxes) and the content of
>   any web page you visit. To use a High
>   Contrast theme on Windows, go to Start
>   Menu > Control Panel > Accessibility
>   Options > Display and check the "Use
>   High Contrast" option.

Answer (score 0):

First try the Microsoft Clear Type Tuner:
http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/Step1.aspx
This tool allows global text rendering settings to be tuned for Windows. If you pick one of the darker flavours, all type in Windows will look darker.